# How to use fallback source on ScriptTagHelper and LinkTagHelper correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, fallback, tag-helpers

I have read following posts from Damian Edwards.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1576

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1580

At the `ScriptTagHelper`, I'm not sure what I should enter on `asp-fallback-test attribute`? It's the same as for `jQuery`? `window.jQuery`? How do I find the correct `JavaScript` Expression? Can someone give me an example based on `moment-withlocales.min.js`? Thanks!

Is following example for the `LinkTagHelper` correct?

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css"
  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"
  asp-fallback-test-class="daterangepicker"
  asp-fallback-test-property="position"
  asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
/>
```

Michael.

Comment: Have you found an answer? Also I wonder how do I test composite classes , for example " .wide-div .inner-class { visibility: hidden; } "

Answer (score 5):

```
<script src="//whatever.cdn.com/moment.js"
    asp-fallback-src="lib/moment.js"
    asp-fallback-test="window.moment">
```

The fallback test is some function in the js file that will be defined by the js script. If the function is undefined then it loads the fallback script.