# ASP.NET Script Tag Helpers - Choosing between fallback options

Tags: c#, asp.net, polyfills, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm studying for an exam, one of the questions involves polyfills in ASP.NET. I understand the purpose, but I can't figure out how to select the correct fallback test on certain elements between:

*asp-fallback-test-property*

*asp-fallback-test*

**An example question has this layout:**

```
<script [asp-fallback-*OPTION*] = "window.Promise"
   asp-fallback-src = "https://somesource.com/promise" >
</script>
```

Tried reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.scripttaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.1), but it doesn't really tell me when to use either option. From the name it would seem obvious, in the case of a library - not so much.

My javascript knowledge is pretty weak, which makes this type of thing more difficult.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: in connection with the script tag, it can look at a property and a value (of that property), so the only server-side attributes that apply are `asp-fallback-test-property` and `asp-fallback-test-value`, but never `asp-fallback-test`

Comment: In that example (possible duplicate question) where it checks a test-property and then the value it makes sense. Is it possible to not have a value check? In the example I've given will the asp-fallback-test-property be sufficient? As it doesn't really have a value and the option isn't there in the question to add a following line.

Comment: oops right: there is the use case to check for *existence* of a js object. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420483/1132334